# Typing over text and keeping the existing text

Tags: microsoft-word

I hope that this is the correct place to ask this question.

I have some PDFs that have been converted into Word and I am now trying to tidy them up so that they match the original as much as possible. These PDFs are from scans from hard copy documents that were originally created via a typewriter. As such there are areas where text has been written over the top of other text. For example there might be a row of dots for a form type layout and then the value typed over the top. Or in some cases existing options have been covered with x's to indicate that it is not used.

I have looked at underlining but the styles available aren't that similar and are too close to the text bottom. I also tried to create a row of dots on the line below and then adjusted the spacing which looks much more like the original but then the dots are too far from the text.

These also don't cover how to overlay existing text in the case of the x's that are in use.

Any thoughts on how to accomplish this would be appreciated. I am using Word 2007 and there is no scope to use anything else.

Thanks

Comment: Could you attach a screenshot of the underlining? For the overlay text you can create a transparent textbox over the original text and add the second layer of text there.

Comment: @Adam Transparent text boxes did exactly what I needed for the underlining and for the text overlay. I think this should be put as an answer to the question. Thank you very much!

Comment: Glad to hear that suggestion solved both questions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a transparent textbox over the original text and add the second layer of text there. You can use a similar technique for producing different types of underlines as well.